# Website throws IE9 into Compability mode

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9

this link works great with chrome and firefox 4 http://cluster005.ovh.net/~bquadint/drmonod/

However, if i view it with IE9, it throws it into **IE9 Compat View / Document mode: IE7 Standards**

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often that can happen when there is a problem with your doctype .. like if it were missing. That's the first place I'd look. It would be difficult to troubleshoot further without code to sift through.

Comment: True true, did you set the browser mode back to 9 and clear the cache? Visiting the link fresh from here I did not come across the bug you mentioned. I check back into the doctype issue I mentioned and I found that a missing doctype will jump the browser to quirks mode.